# SVN Switch from branch to trunk

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

I am currently in `/branches/private/issueNum` and I want to go back to `/trunk/` without bringing any of the changes I had made in `/branches/private/issueNum` so I can then start working on a new issue.

I am just unsure if I should be using `svn switch .../trunk/` or `svn checkout .../trunk`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case the working copy has no local uncommitted modifications, run [`svn switch ^/trunk`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html). The switch will complete faster than a clean checkout and it will not move any changes from ^^/branches/private/issueNum to the trunk.

You can also run [`svn checkout`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) to obtain a clean new working copy of trunk. But it's going to take a bit more time (actually depends on the size of the project) than switching.

Read the documentation: [SVNBook | Traversing branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.switchwc.html).

Comment: Thanks for help. I was unsure if `switch` would move over commited changes or not. Turns out it doesn't, just don't want to mess up `trunk`.